# Print CArray in series instead of new line

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to print the `CArrayDouble` type of array in series. But instead it is printing line by line. This is not the case with normal array. See below:

```
double KArray[];
ArrayPrint(KArray);
43.95604 13.97849  9.67742 10.71429 23.07692
```

But when I did the same with the CArrayDouble type variable array thenit print on newline each output not in series.

```
CArrayDouble KArray;
for (int i = 0; i< KArray.Total(); i++){PrintFormat("Element: %f", KArray[i]);}
Element: 43.95604 
Element: 13.97849  
Element: 9.67742 
Element: 10.71429 
Element: 23.07692
```

I want to print them as:

```
Element: 43.95604 13.97849  9.67742 10.71429 23.07692
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Print` or `PrintFormat` are kind of `println` in other languages. Unfortunately there is no way (to the best of my belief) to use something like `print` in other languages. So you have to declare `string`, add values and then `printf` at the end.

```
string line="";
for(int i=0;i<Array.Total();i++)line+=" "+KArray.At(i);
printf("Elements : %s",line);
```